# Response with bad encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, yelp

I have request to yelp, where i get a venue by id. All working successfull, but i find one issue with id, which return yelp.

```
"yelp_id" = "caf\U00e9-de-paris-london-6";
```

Bad encoding, and venue doesn't show. Should be this - `"yelp_id" = "cafe-de-paris-london-6";`

How to fix this issue? Help please.

P.S. data in json 
for example: `{
            address = "3-4 Coventry Street";
            id = 2;
            "is_subscribed" = 0;
            latitude = "51.51052449";
            longitude = "-0.131816821801";
            owner =             {
                "fb_id" = 513707602107780;
            };
            "start_at" = "2014-07-31T15:40:40.333Z";
            title = new;
            "yelp_id" = "caf\U00e9-de-paris-london-6";
        }
    );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the ID is incorrect.

The `\U00e9` character you are getting is `é`. The `yelp_id` is a UTF-8 string so the human readable ID is `café-de-paris-london-6`.

Comment: you right but in my app i get a venue by id, and when i tap on cafe de paris i have an error: "Load yelp venue error:bad URL", because he don't understand this symbol " é "

Comment: I think you have to call `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` on a string you use to construct URL to convert `é` back to its unicode notation.

Comment: str = [yelpId stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] returns me same result with bad symbol

Comment: Resolved by adding this code in url [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];